# How to get NAT to show original IP address?

Tags: ubuntu, iptables, nat

I am trying to get our NAT Ubuntu server to send all external internat traffic to our firewall Untrust interface. I see the traffic on the firewall, however the source for all the traffic is coming from 10.5.5.5 (the NAT's private IP). I know it has to do with the masquerade rule, but if I remove the rule I don't get any traffic.

Can a kind soul please help me get the traffic to show the original IP address? Any help would be much appreciated!

Firwall private IP: 10.5.1.4
NAT private IP: 10.5.5.5

Here are my rules so far:

```
sudo sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 50022 -j DNAT --to 10.5.5.5:22
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.5.1.4
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE
```

EDIT-
What I'm trying to accomplish: We have a Palo Alto firewall deployed in Azure.  Azure only allows one public IP per VM. And in this situation we need the public IP assigned to the management interface of the firewall. So we need a NAT VM with a public IP to forward all traffic from its public interface to the Untrust interface of the Palo Alto firewall. I need the firewall to see the original outside internet traffic. The NAT VM and Firewall VM are in the same VNET in Azure.

Comment: What are trying to accomplish?   Is this for a load balancer or showing the IP for stat analysis in an app or....?

Comment: What exactly do you want the firewall to see? The inside NATted traffic or the outside Internet traffic? How is it connected?

Comment: I just edited to add more information. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your `MASQUERADE` rule applies to all traffic regardless of interface. You should pretty much always restrict `MASQUERADE` to the intended outgoing interface, which in your case would be `eth0`

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```